# Godot - Unexpected token: Identifier:"Function name"

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make a wave game in Godot and I tried making for loops but I couldn't get them to work outside a function. But when I did put it in the function Godot won't recognize the function and give me this error - error(27,1): Unexpected token: Identifer:spawnEnemies

Code:

```
extends Node2D

var screenSize = get_viewport().get_visible_rect().size

func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

var scene = preload("res://scenes/enemyInstance.tscn")

func _physics_process(delta):
    pass

func spawnEnemy():
    var instance = scene.instance()
    var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
    var rndX = rng.randi_range(0, screenSize.x)
    var rndY = rng.randi_range(0, screenSize.y)
    instance.position.x = rndX
    instance.position.y = rndY
    add_child(instance)

func spawnEnemies(number):
    for i in number:
        spawnEnemy()


spawnEnemies(7)
```

I've tried removing the for loop or changing how the variables are but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GDScript does not support top level statements.**

Thus, this line is invalid:

```
spawnEnemies(7)
```

The error, in fact, is telling you that it didn't expect to find `spawnEnemies` there. *It has nothing to do with a loop or variables.*

So, when exactly do you want that to execute? Given that your code requires to access the scene tree (it uses `add_child`) it cannot be when the object has just be initialized (i.e. in `_init`), it must also be in the scene tree. We have a method for that `_enter_tree`.

Turns out there is one more wrinkle. If there are children defined from the editor, those have not been added yet in `_enter_tree`. Which might result in Godot saying that the node is busy. The error has this text: "Parent node is busy setting up children, add_node() failed. Consider using call_deferred("add_child", child) instead.".

Thus, just use the `_ready` that the template gives you, unless you have a reason not to:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    spawnEnemies(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* put arbitrary chunks of code at the top-level of a script file. GDScript isn't Python. If you intend that code to run at object construction time, put it in `_init` (or `_ready` to run when the node enters the scene tree). If you intend that it run at game startup, then put it in the `_ready` method of an [autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html).

Comment: Note `_ready` execute after the node is in the scene tree, and all the children set in the editor are in the scene tree, and all the `_ready` of all the children have executed too.